# Qtp uft count the links number on a webpage:Count function is not recognized

Tags: hyperlink, html, qtp, hp-uft

I'm trying to count the number of links in a web page, using QTP UFT version 14 build 1775, but the count function is not recognized, maybe it has been deprecated. If someone has an idea about the issue, i'll be thankful for your help.

The is the code that I used

```
Set desc=description.Create()
desc("micclass").value="Link"

Set objLink =Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("title:=.*").childobjects(desc)

msgbox bjLink.count
```

[image]

Comment: Typo.  You set `objLink` to the collection and are trying to get the count of `bjLink`

Comment: omg you'r right. thank you it's working now. But the count function is not in a blue color as other functions, as you can see in screen shot. is it normal ?

Comment: Neither is the `.value` on your desc object, or the `.childobjects` method of the Page object.  Perfectly normal.  The blue only applies to keywords, not every function.

Comment: thank you so much. You could put it in the answer field , so i set it to resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.  You're setting the `objLink` reference then trying to get the `Count` property from `bjLink`.  Change that to `objLink.Count` and it will work as expected

```
Set desc=description.Create()
desc("micclass").value="Link"

Set objLink =Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("title:=.*").childobjects(desc)

msgbox objLink.count
```